# Android : String method return Null

Tags: android

I know that this Question is repeated but I can't find the answer in Internet.

`02-10 11:03:28.465  22410-22767/com.eztimetable.eztimetable I/System.out﹕ ERROR : null
02-10 11:03:28.465  22410-22767/com.eztimetable.eztimetable I/System.out﹕ error
02-10 11:03:28.595  22410-22410/com.eztimetable.eztimetable E/log_tag﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

why am i getting error / null ?

Below is the method that i use

```
//in LecturerScreen class
    public String getDataFromDB() {
    try {
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.9/my_folder_inside_htdocs/retrieve.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
        //add your data
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        // Always use the same variable name for posting i.e the android side variable name and php side variable name should be similar,
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("inputUser",inputUser.getText().toString().trim()));  // $Edittext_value = $_POST['Edittext_value'];
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);

        return response.trim();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
        return "error";
    }
}
```

and this is how i call the method

```
    //in LecturerTimetable class
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lecturer_timetable);

    tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

    final LecturerScreen getdb = new LecturerScreen();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
            System.out.println(data);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<TimetableDisplay> timetable = parseJSON(data);
                    addData(timetable);
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}
```

I dont know what where my wrong here. Could someone give me solution for this question.

I am very new in developing Android program, so if anyone could guide, it would be an honor.
Sorry for bad english.
Thank you.

--UPDATE--

the php script

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="eztimetable";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$lecturerUser = $_POST['inputUser'];
$query_search = "select lecturerCode from lectureraccount where lecturerId = '".$lecturerUser."'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search,$localhost) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_exec))
        $json_output[]=$row;

print(json_encode($json_output));

mysql_close();
```

?>

Comment: You're not returning anything when your try block succeeds.

Comment: Hi prudhvi , what should i do ? can you give some solution? sorry , i am very new to programming..

Comment: My bad, I see you're returning 'response.trim()'. But check if your response is referring to null. Add 'Log.w("String", response);' just below final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler); and paste the Log message you get.

Comment: I add the line and it gives the same Log message as in the question.

Comment: @SkyClasher What kind of response are you expecting from the URL?

Comment: hi @iRuth , the php file will parse data from the database to the response.

Comment: @SkyClasher Do you have an example of the response the PHP script returns?

Comment: the respons is like this `[{"lecturerCode":"C-AMIRUL","subject":"PA","program":"DIP6B","classLocation":"CNW3","day":"Thursday","startHours":"11:00 AM","endHours":"12:00 PM","hours":"1 H"},{"lecturerCode":"C-AMIRUL","subject":"FP601","program":"DIP6C ","classLocation":"CNW1","day":"Monday","startHours":"11:00 AM","endHours":"12:00 PM","hours":"1 H"}]`

Comment: @SkyClasher I have added an answer. Let me know if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing this error (`Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`) because your response is a `JSONArray` and you are treating it as a String. In order to get rid of the error, replace `return response.trim();` with `return response;`. Since you are already processing the JSON response in your activity's `onCreate` using `parseJSON(data)`, I think that should fix the problem.

Let me know if it does.

**Edit**

Try removing the `ResponseHandler` and executing the request without it:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Also, change the way you instantiated the `nameValuePairs`. Remove the "2" and just instantiate it like this:

```
nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
```

**Edit 2**

You should always "sanitize" the user's input. In your case, you needed to confirm that the user's input was not empty.

```
String inputUserString = inputUser.getText().toString().trim();

if (!inputUserString.isEmpty()) {
    // execute the httppost request here

} else {
    // display an error message to the user

}
```

Comment: `Error:(178, 49) error: incompatible types: HttpResponse cannot be converted to String` when i try remove the `ResponseHandler` . i change the way i instantiated the `nameValuePairs` and still get the same error.

Comment: I see where your problem is. `response` is of type `HttpResponse` and not `String`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: the error is still the same, i still getting null.. But i found something, if i remove `nameValuePairs` ,  i will get the respons, but i need `nameValuePairs` to parse my `inputUser` to my php file. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How did you declare `nameValuePairs` and `inputUser`?

Comment: This is how i declared it .`EditText inputUser; List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;` 
`inputUser =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputId);`

Comment: I added `responseCode` to my answer. Let me know what the `responseCode` returns.

Comment: `responseCode` return 0 .

Comment: Okay. Confirm that the android device has network access (e.g. try opening a page in the web browser). Also confirm that, given the expected input, your PHP script gives an output.

Comment: Also confirm that `inputUser.getText().toString().trim()` contains a `String`.

Comment: Could you also update your question with the PHP script?

Comment: okay, i have confirmed that the device has network access and the php script gives an output.

Comment: In the SQL query of your PHP script, what data type is `lecturerId`? And what are you sending from `inputUser`? A number or a text?

Comment: `lecturerId` datatype is `varchar` and the `inputUser` is `String`. i mean text

Comment: Okay. Did you check if the `inputUser` is empty?

Comment: okay , the problem is at the `inputUser` .. it is sending empty value.

Comment: Okay. I have updated my answer. Can you accept it as answer, since that's what worked?

Answer (score 0):

Before you use 'response.trim()', you need to check if your response is referring to null:

```
final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost,responseHandler);
if (response != null) {
    response = response.trim();
}
return response;
```

Comment: if the response is referring to null, what should i do?